# Computing estimates with rma.glmm: Error when the 2 estimates are identical

Tags: r, metafor

I am using rma.glmm to meta proportions from 2 different studies. For example, the proportion of individuals with (xi) and without (xii) an adverse event at 6 months:

```
library(metafor)

#6 months
study=c("1", "2")
ni = c(41, 19)
xi = c(26, 14)
xii = c(15, 5)
NP6monthAT <- data.frame(study, xi, xii, ni)
res2 <- rma.glmm(measure="PLO", xi = xi, ni = ni, data = NP6monthAT)
predict (res2, transf = transf.ilogit, digits=2)
res2 <- rma.glmm(measure = "PLO", xi = xii, ni = ni, data = NP6monthAT)
predict (res2, transf = transf.ilogit, digits=2)
```

HOWEVER, by chance at a specific timepoint, both proportions in the 2 different populations are identical (11.1%) and I receive an error:

```
#12 months
study=c("1", "2")
ni=c(81, 45)
xi=c(9, 5)
xii=c(72, 40)
NNPNNP12monthAT<-data.frame(study, xi, xii, ni)
res4<-rma.glmm(measure="PLO", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=NNPNNP12monthAT)
predict(res4, transf=transf.ilogit, digits=2)
```

Error in rma.glmm(measure = "PLO", xi = xi, ni = ni, data = NNPNNP12monthAT) : 
  Cannot fit ML model.

I understand the estimate will be equal to 11.1 (as that's what it is in both populations)... but I want the output with the confidence interval, any advice on what I can do to get this information?

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post a reproducible example, where people can run your code and reproduce your error.

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp I did include the code, it is listed above. it can be run and produce the error.

Comment: you need to define `study` in your code for it to be reproducible.

Comment: ok, study is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem stems from `lme4::glmer()` which is used to fit this model:

```
> glmer(cbind(xi,ni-xi) ~ 1 + (1 | study), family=binomial, data=NNPNNP12monthAT)
Error: Response is constant
```

There obviously cannot be any between-study heterogeneity when the log odds are the same across studies. A simple solution is to fit a FE model then (since with `tau^2` equal to 0, this is what you would get anyway). So, use:

```
res4 <- rma.glmm(measure="PLO", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=NNPNNP12monthAT, method="FE")
```