# GLMM's for meta-analysis - error using metabin

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models

I'm trying to run a generalised linear mixed effects (binomial-normal) meta-analysis for 7 randomised studies, where each study records the presence of an adverse event within the treatment and placebo populations (exposure and control).

To do this, I'm hoping to use the [metabin function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/meta/versions/4.9-2/topics/metabin) (meta package). However, I'm getting an error and I'm not sure why. E.g. running this code:

```
install.packages('meta')
# Data
data<-data.frame(exposure.events=c(11,34,152,4,60,3,25), exposure.population=c(184,152,9500,77,2012,15,60), control.events=c(3,33,4729,133,1441,1,25), control.population=c(184,375,613978,15865,480485,105,238), Study=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7"))
# Calling metabin
metabin(event.e=exposure.events, n.e=exposure.population, event.c=control.events, n.c=control.population, studlab=Study, data=data, method="GLMM",model.glmm = "CM.AL",method.tau = "ML")
```

I get this output:

> Error in metafor::rma.glmm(ai = event.e[!exclude], n1i = n.e[!exclude],  : 
>     Cannot fit ML model.

I've also tried calling the rma.glmm function directly (instead of doing this via metabin), but get the same error message. I've also tried reading the [source code for rma.glmm](https://rdrr.io/cran/metafor/src/R/rma.glmm.r) but I'm not sure I understand what's going on. However, I think the issue is related to the third study (the largest), and in particular the size of the control population, as both of the following run smoothly:

```
# Modifying 3rd row's control population
data<-data.frame(exposure.events=c(11,34,152,4,60,3,25), exposure.population=c(184,152,9500,77,2012,15,60), control.events=c(3,33,4729,133,1441,1,25), control.population=c(184,375,61378,15865,480485,105,238), Study=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7"))
metabin(event.e=exposure.events, n.e=exposure.population, event.c=control.events, n.c=control.population, studlab=Study, data=data, method="GLMM",model.glmm = "CM.AL",method.tau = "ML")

# Deleting 3rd row
data<-data.frame(exposure.events=c(11,34,4,60,3,25), exposure.population=c(184,152,77,2012,15,60), control.events=c(3,33,133,1441,1,25), control.population=c(184,375,15865,480485,105,238), Study=c("1","2","3","4","5","6"))
metabin(event.e=exposure.events, n.e=exposure.population, event.c=control.events, n.c=control.population, studlab=Study, data=data, method="GLMM",model.glmm = "CM.AL",method.tau = "ML")
```

Is this a convergence problem, and does anyone know if there is any way around this? The only other thing I can find about this error message is for [a problem (and thus solution) which does not apply to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723944/computing-estimates-with-rma-glmm-error-when-the-2-estimates-are-identical).

Any help would be really appreciated :)